# Showing connected nodes of the Data Layer as a list

Tags: android, wear-os

I'm trying to show a list in my App with the current nodes connected to the DataLayer but I'm struggling to find a solution since I cannot call `Wearable.NodeApi.getConnectedNodes(googleClient).await()` from the UI Thread. I've also tried to set a ResultCallback for the PendingResult which would show the dialog with the Display Name of the nodes, but it doesn't seem to be calling it.

I would appreciate your help. Thank you!

Comment: The `ResultCallback` approach should work. Can you post a code snippet showing how you tried to implement that?